# how to touch nginx cache file via php

Tags: php, caching, nginx

Usually to flush nginx cache, I use the unix command :

```
touch /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/cache.flush
```

I'd like to know if I can do the same with php in order not to log on SSH to do it.

If yes, would this code work ? :

```
<?php

    $flush_file = "/var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/cache.flush";
    touch($flush_file);

?>
```

If not, could you point me on how to please ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It should. Just make sure php has correct permissions for this file.

Comment: @Andrew Hello and thank you for your input, how would I achieve that (the most secure way) please ?

Answer (score 0):

*Reposted my own comment above for better formatting.*

Well, I guess it would be safe enough to chown this file to user which run php/webserver ex. `www-data`. Then give him write permission on this file.

On Debian server it would be somethings like this:

`sudo chown www-data /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/cache.flush
sudo chmod +w /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/cache.flush`